# How can I name or rename a VB 2010 object or property on the fly?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, object, rename, vb.net-2010

I would like to create an object on the fly supplying parameters for the object and properties.

Or be able to rename the object name (and therefore it's reference) and its property names.

Example:

```
Create("OBJECT1", "PROPERTY1", "PROPERTY2")
```

to end up with an object that can be accessed by:

```
OBJECT1.PROPERTY1.text = "Property1 Value"
```

Or create an Object:

```
CLASS obj
  Property prop1 as string
  Property prop2 as string
END CLASS

Dim myObj as new obj
myObj.prop1.text = "Propert 1 Value"

(Somehow rename)
myObj.prop1.Name = "PROPERTY1"
myObj.prop2.Name = "PROPERTY2"
myObj.Name = "OBJECT1"
```

Giving OBJECT1.PROPERTY1.text as "Property 1 Value"

THANKS IN ADVANCE FOR ANY HELP!

Comment: Can i ask why you need it? What is your real requirement? You could use reflection but it's inefficient and normally there are better options.

Comment: I have a ton of different data files with different data structures(fieldnames)  I do not want to hardcode them into our procedures.  I want to be able to read them in and build an object reflective of its structure.  For example XML files.  The have a hierarchy and naturally lend themselves to an object that is accessible in a manner like CLIENT.NAME.FIRSTNAME="Bob" where the object "client" is named on the fly based on the XML element with its children "Name" and grandchildren "FIRSTNAME" are derived again from the XML.  (XML, comma delimited text, fixed length, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I would go with anonymous types, they are very easy to instantiate:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx

Comment: +1 would you be able to elaborate for the newby, with a code example. Cheers!

Comment: Wow.  This looks VERY promising!  Will check them out ASAP!!  THANKS!

Comment: Darn.  No-go.  You need to know the name of the object and properties ahead of time...  I need to be able to name them at runtime after I have discovered what they are...